# How to do one line assignment to malloc() arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, heap-memory

In C I can initialize an array on the stack like so:

```
SOME_DATA_TYPE* x = (SOME_DATA_TYPE[5]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};
```

Is there a similar one-line method to assign values to a `malloc()`-ed array on the heap?

```
SOME_DATA_TYPE* y = malloc(sizeof(SOME_DATA_TYPE)*5);  
// what comes here?
```

Or do I have to iterate over the array and assign values individually?

Comment: What about `*y = (SOME_DATA_TYPE[5]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5};`?

Comment: malloc just wants a size. calculate the size of your nested structure and ask for that many bytes.

Comment: @DaBler The right side is interpreted as stack memory. I know this because `free(y)` then crashes my application.

Comment: If you mean `x`: that is not an array! If it was an array, it would not be called "pointer".

Comment: Then you could use `memcpy(y, (SOME_DATA_TYPE[5]){v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, sizeof(SOME_DATA_TYPE)*5);`...

Comment: why do want to dab with one liners? It is better to use more than one line of code for clarity and maintainability.

Comment: I find it convenient when I'm testing out new code/features for the first time. Plus I'd like to know if there is a maintainable/readable one-liner available out there. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue about "initializing" the result of `malloc()` is that the allocation may fail.  Here `y` is *initialized* to some pointer value.  The data referenced is still indeterminate.

```
#define  element_count  5
SOME_DATA_TYPE *y = malloc(sizeof *y * element_count);
if (y == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
```

With C11, code can use *compound literals* to set, not *initialize*, the data pointed to by `y`.

```
memcpy(y, (SOME_DATA_TYPE[element_count]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, sizeof *y * element_count);
```

---

Using a *direct* one-liner without checking the allocation would not be robust programming.

```
// one-liner, but not robust code
SOME_DATA_TYPE *y = memcpy(malloc(sizeof *y * element_count), 
    (SOME_DATA_TYPE[element_count]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, sizeof *y * element_count);
```

---

Notice code uses the `sizeof *pointer_variable * element_count` rather than `sizeof (pointer_variable_dereferenced_type) * element_count` as easier to code, less error prone, easier to review and maintain.  Either approach will work.

Comment: This code is incorrect - it may call Handle_OutOfMemory() if the array size is zero.

Comment: @TLW Good eye.  Yes, for a general test of the result of `malloc()`, code should use `if (y == NULL && element_count > 0) Handle_OutOfMemory();`  Of course, as OP wants "initialize an array", an array size of 0 has other problems beyond `malloc()` like `SOME_DATA_TYPE[element_count]`.  I would have coded the `element_count > 0` test had `element_count` been a variable.

Comment: It'd be possible to check the malloc result in the one-liner with some abuse of the comma operator... certainly would take us out of the bounds of "maintainable/readable" though

Comment: @M.M Agreed.  Yet it sounds like OP is primary doing this for test purpose anyways, so many OOM it not a concern?

Answer (score 3):

You could define a function like so:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * intMallocInit (int length, ...) {
   // Initialize Variable Arguments
   va_list args;
   va_start (args, length); 

    // Allocate Memory
    int * arr = malloc (sizeof(int) * length);
    if (arr == NULL) return NULL;

    // Initialize Array
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = va_arg(args, int);
    }

    // Clean Up and Return
    va_end(args)
    return arr;
}
```

And we could call it like so:

```
int len = 3;
int * myArray = intMallocInit (len, 4, 5, 2);
if (myArray == NULL) return 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%d,", myArray [i]);
}
```

**Output:** 4,5,2,

**Note:** We could also define floatMallocInit (), etc. simply by replacing every instance of "int" in the above function to "float"

You could also use void pointers, or enum& switch, but I wont go there.

**Untested attempt at general function**
Im sure theres a clever work around fhe switchs but this is what I can come up with.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
enum {INT, FLOAT /* etc...*/}

 int getSize(int type) {
     int typeSize = 0;
     switch (type) {
        case INT: 
             typeSize = sizeof (int);
             break;
        case FLOAT:
             typeSize = sizeof (float);
             break;
        // Etc...
        default:
             return -1;
    }
    return typeSize;
 }


void * mallocInit (int type, int length, ...) {
   // Initialize Variable Arguments
   va_list args;
   va_start (args, length); 

    // Get Size of type
    int typeSize = getSize(type);
    if (typeSize == -1) return NULL;

    // Allocate Memory
    void * arr = malloc (typeSize * length);
    if (arr == NULL) return NULL;

    // Initialize Array, Maybe va_copy can be used? No good reference
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         switch(type) {
            case INT:
             arr[i] = va_args(args, int);
             break;
            // Etc..
        }
    }

    // Clean Up and Return
    va_end(args)
    return arr;
}
```

Called with

```
float myArray = mallocInit (FLOAT, 3, 1, 5, 7);
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution!

Comment: Sorry, but how what does type mean? I never used `...`as of right now, could you please briefly explain how it works?

Comment: I modified  it to make it more clear. The ... represents a variable number of parameters. (You have to include <stdarg>) Check tutorialpoint it has a good reference.

Comment: `arr[i] = args[i];`?!?!  That doesn't even compile.  At best, that's non-standard.  You need to use `arr[i] = va_arg(args, int);`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++;)` does not compile, its `va_arg`, not `va_args`, and it should be `va_end (args);` not `va_end`. (otherwise, nice function)

Comment: `arr[i] = va_arg(args, void);` --> ``void` is not the right type

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without getting too far away from the natural C memory management philosophy, is to use a [`memdup`](http://man.cx/memdup(3))-like function. Since it is not standard, you might have to implement it yourself

```
SOME_DATA_TYPE *y = memdup(
  (SOME_DATA_TYPE[5]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5},
  5 * sizeof(SOME_DATA_TYPE));
```

Comment: Hmmm, good to know.  LSNED.   Perhaps could use a `#define MEMDUP(x) (memdup((x), sizeof (x)))` to simply the call to `MEMDUP((SOME_DATA_TYPE[5]) {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5})`?